# Facebook log in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this code in order to get the email

```
string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)){
                string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
                FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
```

And on the click event I defined this:

```
        FaceBookConnect.Authorize("email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]);
```

The problem is that it gives me a null value as email, i tried doing the same for the name and it is the only field that actually works. I read that thay have changed the version to v2.6 and it is necessary to do the facebookConnect.Fetch in another way, but I am unable to find how. Anyone knows something? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested the email info from Facebook? You must do that at start of login and the user has to approve this before Facebook will provide it. Facebook also says it will be null if the address is not valid or if they used a phone number to sign up:

"*Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.*"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

Comment: Yes, it is requested in the FaceBookConnect.Authorize, and on the facebook webpage I get a message saying that if I want to share my personal information and email, but when I accept, the email is null

Comment: Updated my answer there with more relevant text. I take it the user on Facebook actually has a user account?

Comment: Yes, I saw that on the facebook link, but the user has email, that's why I dont understand why it is null, I've been hours trying to find it out but I don't know

Comment: is your app in developer mode? It has to be because that permission requires a review of your app by Facebook before they'll supply it. I doubt they'd ask the user for permission without being reviewed so that's just a wild guess.